# Multiple exposed form blocks with different fields

Tags: views, 8

Scenario:

View fields:

```
name
gender
age
especialty
```

exposed form block (1) fields:

```
name
especialty
```

exposed form block (2) fields:  (This is also I want to have but as a separate block)

```
 name
 age
 gender
```

I am looking for a way in which I can have **two different exposed form blocks**  but with different search fields.

I am using Drupal 8. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably need to make 2 custom forms in code and a custom block for each form to display them. Then in your form submits you'll need to replicate the url parameters views would normally do e.g. ?field_my_field=2&field_my_field2=aaa

Comment: in addition to the @Leigh suggestion (which is great, I did it this way too a month ago) do not forget to add redirect on form submit to the views path with $_GET params, views exposed filter should be detached anyway so expose in block = yes in views advanced config but not show the block anywhere.

Comment: The "interface" solution could be to Duplicate the Views Page, keep the same Path setting, but override the Exposed Filters so you end up with two different Exposed form blocks. That way you have two Exposed filter Blocks working on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

On my Drupal 9.5x project, the old duplicate page method works.
Steps:

- Create a page display with all the desired fields and the set of exposed filters you want in block1.
- Duplicate the page display.(Path = same as the first.)
- On the duplicated page, remove the block1 exposed filters and add the filters wanted in block2.
- Check the expose filters in a block option on both page displays.
- Go to block layout and add the two exposed filter blocks to the page for the view.

In my case I have auto-refresh enabled and the submit button disabled. The filters apply as expected.